# Show a limited number of digits after the decimal

Tags: c++

Consider the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int a;
  double b;
  cout << "Enter a number to be divided by three" << endl;
  cin >> a;
  b = a / 3.0;
  cout << "The result of this is:" << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I set how many variables I would like to store after the decimal point? This includes above 20 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` is a fixed-size type (8 bytes on most systems). So it only stores numbers to a certain precision. There's no need to fear "infinite division" (in the sense that 1/3.0 has no finite decimal representation).

**Edit** (based on comments below)

If you are actually looking for an arbitrary-precision real number representation, you have to use a library for that, such as [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I understand but how to a force it to become a fixed size?

Comment: @Griffin Do you mean `b = 0.1 * std::round(10.0 * (a / 3.0));`?

Comment: Yes and no. That will have the output I am looking for but not the effect. I would like to control the number of places after the decimal it is divided. This includes making the numbers after the decimal longer than standard and shorter than standard. In this particular case I am looking to just figure out if the output will be a decimal. I don't care what the decimal is just looking the make sure there is none. Please note when I say looking to see if there is a decimal I mean a decimal other than 0. So 3.0 would be okay but 3.1 , 3.2 , 3.3 and so on are not.

Comment: That was worded incorrectly also. I know I can use the modulus function in order to do this. So in order to not make myself not look like more of an idiot I am going to make it short and sweet. How do I control the number of decimal places after the zero. Either increasing or decreasing them. I would like to be able to set a fixed number. Almost like how you can set a max length in html. Thank you and sorry for the mass confusion. These last few days have been chaos and my not thinking clearly is showing through.

Comment: @Griffin Just to clarify - are you talking about representation of the number in memory, or about some form of output/conversion to string?

Comment: The end result would be a number. I would like to set the number of places after the decimal point. For example say I would like to display the first 1000 numbers of pi. How do I set it so it gives the first 1000.

Comment: @Griffin If you really need something this precise, you'll have to look at a library to do it (such as [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)).

Comment: Thank you. Would you post that as an answer because I would like to approve it as the correct answer for future people with the same problem.

Comment: @Griffin Edited the answer to provide the link.

Comment: @Griffin My rep log shows that this answer was downvoted recently. I was just wondering who did it and why.

Comment: Ohhh. I recently edited the post so that might have something to do with it. I don't know sorry.

Comment: @Griffin Nevermind. I wasn't asking because of the rep, I was just curious why someone considered the answer wrong. They didn't, apparently :-)

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be under the impression that the resulting answer of `1/3` will be `0.33333333333...[to infinity]`.

That is not correct.  Floating-point numbers only have limited accuracy, and the resulting value would only be out to about 20 digits or so, **not** an infinite number of digits.

Variable `b` will have all the precision a variable of type `double` can handle.  There's no easy way to limit that.

However, if you only want to limit how much you display, you can restrict the output shown by `cout`:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << b << endl;
```

- `fixed` will cause the output to use Fixed Point notation (the other option is `scientific`).
- `setprecision` will control the maximum number of digits to be shown.

The output in this case should be:

```
0.333
```

for a total of 4 digits (1 before the decimal place, and 3 more after it).

Comment: I understand this was for for example rather than actual code and I also understand that it will not divide to infinity. My real question here is how do I limit the number of spaces after the decimal place that I will divide out to.

Comment: Also how do I make it so I can go above 20 digits.

Answer (score 1):

`a/3 = b` should be `b = (double)a/3`. And it only divides once!
And as iamnotmaynard says: You have to print b not a: `cout << "The result of this is:"<< b << endl;`.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, 1/3 has an infinite decimal representation. In computers, there are no infinite representations. `1/3` divides to integers, and the result is an integer; since an integer doesn't hold fractional parts, the result is 0. If you use doubles instead, `1.0/3.0`, the same kind of thing happens: the result is the best approximation of the mathematical result that fits in a double. So don't be afraid of it. Try it.